# Is LocationManager.addProximityAlert() on pause when the device is asleep?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

Am writing an app that add some points of interest and sends a notification whenever in the range of the POI.the notifications work fine when the phone is on but once the device is asleep the intent is not fired then i don't get any notification (LocationManager.addProximityAlert()).

Any help will be much appreciated it